SnmpSender-object is not initialized
"guard let snmpSender = SnmpSender.shared" does not work. The "fatalError" is always thrown. According to the documentation of the "SwiftSnmpKit" framework, this is a singleton. Here is the code:
import Foundation
import SwiftSnmpKit

public class SnmpMachine {
    private init() {
        
    }
    static func run(agent: String, userName: String, pduType: SnmpPduType, oid: String, password: String, privatePassword: String) async {
        
        
        guard let snmpSender = SnmpSender.shared else {
            fatalError("Snmp Sender not inialized")
        }
        
        

        let result = await snmpSender.send(host: agent, userName: userName, pduType: pduType, oid: oid, authenticationType: .sha1, authPassword: password, privPassword: privatePassword)
            
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print("SNMP Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        case .success(let variableBinding):
            print(variableBinding)
        }
    }
}

The code I use here comes directly from the documentation of the framework. Unfortunately, I don't have any direct ideas as to why it doesn't work (I'm a beginner). But does the ‘shared’ property perhaps not exist?
Thank you in advance for your help!

I see public static let shared: SnmpSender? = try? SnmpSender() https://github.com/darrellroot/SwiftSnmpKit/blob/main/Sources/SwiftSnmpKit/Networking/SnmpSender.swift So something in the init() methods fails https://github.com/darrellroot/SwiftSnmpKit/blob/main/Sources/SwiftSnmpKit/Networking/SnmpSender.swift#L55 the let channel = line... You'd need more debug then. Either try to debug, or post the issue on their github?

If I put "public static let shared: SnmpSender? = try? SnmpSender()" in my code, the following message appears: "'SnmpSender' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level".

That’s because this is the way you implement a singleton, a shared property and a private init. If you’re a complete beginner at programming you might want to take on a simpler learning project that doesn’t involve dependencies to 3rd party libraries. Of course a completely different option is to try to contact the author of the library
